# Is it possible to dynamically set the events I want to bind to in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic, event-handling

I'm currently using this:

```
if ( $.support.touch == true ) {
    $(window).on('orientationchange', function(event){
        if ( full == false ) {
            self.hideAllPanels("7");
        }
    });
} else {
    $(window).on('orientationchange resize', function(event){
        if ( full == false ) {
            self.hideAllPanels("7");
        }
    });
}
```

because I'm getting a lot of resize events triggered on touch devices, when I don't need them.

I also tried the following syntax:

```
$(window).on( ( 'orientationchange'+ ( $.support.touch ? '': ' resize') ), function(event){
    ...
});
```

but this produces an error in Firefox (`app.start()` not defined on line 1` - which is my application, so this doesn't tell me much). Switching back to the first syntax, everything works fine again.

**Question**:
Is it possible to dynamically set the events I want to bind to? If so, what would be the correct synatx in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically setting the events'?

Comment: something like: `case A: bind to orientationchange resize | case B: bind to orientationchange`, so I'm looking for the syntax to do this in the bind-statement = either have the if-else in there or pass a variable with the events applicable. I tried (see above), but I'm getting strange errors, so I was wondering if this is at all possible

Comment: It is possible and your syntax looks correct to me. The outer parens around the string concatenation is unnecessary but shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: code concept shown should work fine

Comment: it looks like you have an extra set of parentheses that _could_ be causing issues: `$(window).on( 'orientationchange'+ ( $.support.touch ? '': ' resize')`

Comment: Your code looks ok. Try to make it a little cleaner: `var event = 'orientationchange' + ($.support.touch ? '' : ' resize');
 $(window).on(event, function() { ... });`. Maybe it will help to find a problem.

Comment: @MattWhipple Parenthesis can't cause the problem. For example `("test" + (true ? "" : " rest"))` is a valid code.

Comment: @dfsq I realize they normally wouldn't as they stand to demarcate an expression which would be treated as equivalent to the expression result but it was a suggestion in case this was just a compiler quirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can minimize code repetition doing something like this:

```
 var events = $.support.touch ? 'orientationchange' : 'orientationchange resize';

$(window).on(events, function(event) {
    if (full == false) {
        self.hideAllPanels("7");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

what's with this

```
function handler( event ) {
    if ( full == false ) {
        self.hideAllPanels("7");
    }
}

$(window).on('orientationchange', handler );

if ( !$.support.touch ) {
    $(window).on( 'resize', handler);
}
```

looks cleaner for me

Comment: This is amazing that you have posted almost character for character identical code to mine :) and you were 40 seconds faster :) (btw: you are missing a parenthesis at the end)

Comment: ok. Like them all. thanks, going with the last answer though. For now. Let's see if this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested but you can probably do it with something like:

```
function handler(event) {
    if ( full == false ) {
        self.hideAllPanels("7");
    }
}
$(window).on('orientationchange', handler);
if ( ! $.support.touch ) {
    $(window).on('resize', handler);
}
```